# How can I programaticly call search on the org chart

Tags: javascript, getorgchart

I'm trying to search the chart using a custom search box, and also default to viewing "the current user" in the chart.  Both boil down to me sending a custom search and showing that node.

Is there a way to perform the search in JS code?  Alternately, is there a way to pan and zoom to the node once I know what it is?  I would also like to flash the node like the default search does.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. You can easely achieve requested functionallity using highlightNode method.

Here is an example: http://www.getorgchart.com/QuickStart/Methods/highlightNode.html

Documentation: http://www.getorgchart.com/Documentation#highlightNode